# Apache Camel FTP getting Cannot retrieve file: RemoteFile error

Tags: java, apache-camel, apache-servicemix, camel-ftp

I'm trying to retrieve files using the Camel FTP component (Camel 2.19.0):

```
from("ftp://my.host.com:21/my/relative/directory?download=true&stepwise=false&delete=false")
```

Camel is connecting and listing the files in the directory correctly, however when it goes to process them, it throws the following exception for each file:

```
org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: Cannot retrieve file: RemoteFile[my/relative/directory/file1.txt] from: ftp://my.host.com:21/my/relative/directory?delete=false&download=true&stepwise=false
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processExchange(GenericFileConsumer.java:427)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.RemoteFileConsumer.processExchange(RemoteFileConsumer.java:137)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processBatch(GenericFileConsumer.java:218)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.poll(GenericFileConsumer.java:182)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:174)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:101)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

From the TRACE logs, I can see that Camel is listing the files in the directory correctly:

```
[TRACE] 2017-09-05 11:40:49,438 org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.FtpConsumer - Polling directory: my/relative/directory
[TRACE] 2017-09-05 11:40:51,748 org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.FtpOperations - listFiles(my/relative/directory)
[TRACE] 2017-09-05 11:40:58,657 org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.FtpConsumer - Found 3 in directory: my/relative/directory
[TRACE] 2017-09-05 11:40:58,657 org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.FtpConsumer - FtpFile[name=/absolute/path/to/directory/file1.txt, dir=false, file=true]
[TRACE] 2017-09-05 11:40:58,657 org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.FtpConsumer - FtpFile[name=/absolute/path/to/directory/file2.txt, dir=false, file=true]
[TRACE] 2017-09-05 11:40:58,657 org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.FtpConsumer - FtpFile[name=/absolute/path/to/directory/file3.txt, dir=false, file=true]
```

When Camel tries to process each file however, it appears to be prepending the relative directory to the absolute directory and failing to find the resulting garbled path:

```
[TRACE] 2017-09-05 11:40:59,417 org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.FtpConsumer - Processing file: RemoteFile[absolute/path/to/directory/file1.txt]
[TRACE] 2017-09-05 11:40:59,418 org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.FtpConsumer - Retrieving file: my/relative/directory//absolute/path/to/directory/file1.txt from: ftp://my.host.com:21/my/relative/directory?delete=false&download=true&stepwise=false
[TRACE] 2017-09-05 11:40:59,418 org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.FtpOperations - retrieveFile(my/relative/directory//absolute/path/to/directory/file1.txt)
[TRACE] 2017-09-05 11:40:59,418 org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.FtpOperations - Client retrieveFile: my/relative/directory//absolute/path/to/directory/file1.txt
[WARN ] 2017-09-05 11:40:59,518 org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.FtpConsumer - Error processing file RemoteFile[absolute/path/to/directory/file1.txt] due to Cannot retrieve file: RemoteFile[absolute/path/to/directory/file1.txt] from: ftp://my.host.com:21/my/relative/directory?delete=false&download=true&stepwise=false
```

This path in the logs constructed by the FTPComponent is incorrect:

> Retrieving file:
>   my/relative/directory//absolute/path/to/directory/file1.txt

I debugged the Camel FTP consumer and it looks like [on line 238 is where the relative path is getting prepended to the absolute path](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/camel-2.19.x/components/camel-ftp/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/file/remote/FtpConsumer.java#L238)

Interestingly enough, [the SFTP component is doing the same thing](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/camel-2.19.x/components/camel-ftp/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/file/remote/SftpConsumer.java#L208) however it is working because `RemoteFileOperations<ChannelSftp.LsEntry>` does not set filename as an absolute path but `RemoteFileOperations<FTPFile>` does.

Does anyone have any suggestions to work around this to get the FTP Conponent to consume the files? or am I doing something incorrectly?

I'm using Camel 2.19.0

Answer (score 0):

By default, camel will go to \home{username}\ directory.
If your file is kept under relative path to this, you only need to give directory path as \abc-any-path\file.txt
If your file is kept at any path other than \home{username}\, then in that case you need to give 
 \ ..\ ..\abc-any-absolute-path\file.txt

Camel won't allow you to enter absolute path directly. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi sorry, this doesn't address my issue.  The issue isn't whether or not relative or absolute paths work - neither do with the Camel FTP component (SFTP does work however).